# XEON Processors 8 cores for heavy processes

Tags: cpu, process

Not sure if this is the right group for my queries but I had to be sure of what I am going to purchase. I did my research already and not sure of it yet as this is my first time doing this. I am planning to host my own desktop server and decided to use a XEON processor with at least 8 cores and 32gb of ram. But I am not sure if this is the right home server for me. My application needs to process at least 20,000,000 SQL queries an hour and has critical mission processes that need to be quick as possible.

Comment: 5600 SQL queries a second?  You might want to start bigger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few considerations which you should take into account (and which are not apparent from your post).   These include -

1. You want as much ram as possible - ideally enough to fit the entire data set in memory.
2. If you are doing any significant number of writes and/or your data can not fit entirely into memory, you need the fastest disk you can get - I don't know the size of your data set, but RAIDED PCI-E SSD's are a good idea - as you talk about it being "mission critical".   Yes, its OK to put a database on SSD - just budget to replace them every 5 years or so.
3. You have mentioned a "desktop server".  I don't believe that this term exists - its either a Desktop, Workstation or Server.  I expect you mean a Server in what was known as a desktop case/form factor - if that is the case, I'd suggest something which will fit on its side in 4u - which is fairly easy to come by if you know to look for it.    Of-course, most desktop cases only have 1 PSU - which could be an issue for reliability and uptime - mission critical servers generally have 2 PSU's on 2 different phases.
4. A large number of (slower cores) is probably better then fewer faster ones, however this will depend on your database and even the type of queries (for example, Postgres 9.5 would not split a single complex query among multiple cores - shifting to Postgres 9.6 did, yielding a close to linear speed increase on some single queries with more cores - so check your database).  Similarly, you should really look at sharding your database so it is less of a bottleneck and you can deploy additional servers as required.
5. If its mission critical, you also need to consider replication - and once you are going this route it may (or may not) make sense to have 1 server doing read-write, and the other being a read-only slave - and modifying your application to take advantage of this.   Again - I wonder if "mission critical" was the correct word to describe your usage.
6. As an aside - you need to consider "Meltdown" and its performance.  Database performance can suffer 20-30% if you add mitigations for it.  If you are not mitigating it - you need to be aware of - and manage the risks (ie make doubly sure its impossible to run arbitary code on it - including ensuring there is no way to do an SQL injection attack)

Despite what others said, if your queries are simple enough, 5000 queries per second is doable - see https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/01/06/millions-queries-per-second-postgresql-and-mysql-peaceful-battle-at-modern-demanding-workloads/

Comment: https://www.itcreations.com/dell/Dell-PowerEdge-T620-Server.asp He's probably looking for a Tower Server you're right. All the components of a blade slapped into a tower.